# Query taking lot of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have three tables Student_details and Student_Marks and subject_Name.

Subject_Name

```
+----+------------------+
| ID |     Sub_Name     |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | Maths            |
|  2 | Physics          |
|  3 | Chemistry        |
|  4 | Biology          |
|  5 | Computer Science |
+----+------------------+
```

Student_details

```
+----+------------+-----------+-----+-------+--+
| ID | First_Name | Last_Name | Age | Class |  |
+----+------------+-----------+-----+-------+--+
|  1 | Rohit      | Sharma    |  28 |     3 |  |
|  2 | Shikhar    | Dhavan    |  27 |     2 |  |
|  3 | Virat      | Kohli     |  29 |     3 |  |
|  4 | MS         | Dhoni     |  30 |     2 |  |
|  5 | Hardik     | Pandya    |  25 |     3 |  |
+----+------------+-----------+-----+-------+--+
```

Student_Marks

```
+----+------------+------------+---------------+
| ID | Student_Id | Subject_Id | Subject_Marks |
+----+------------+------------+---------------+
|  1 |          1 |          1 |            90 |
|  2 |          1 |          2 |            82 |
|  3 |          1 |          3 |            85 |
|  4 |          1 |          4 |            75 |
|  5 |          1 |          5 |            92 |
|  6 |          2 |          1 |            90 |
|  7 |          2 |          2 |            82 |
|  8 |          2 |          3 |            85 |
|  9 |          2 |          4 |            75 |
| 10 |          2 |          5 |            92 |
| 11 |          3 |          1 |            90 |
| 12 |          3 |          2 |            82 |
| 13 |          3 |          3 |            85 |
| 14 |          3 |          4 |            75 |
| 15 |          3 |          5 |            92 |
+----+------------+------------+---------------+
```

and I'm using this query to fetch the result.

```
select sd.First_Name
      ,sd.Last_Name
      ,sm.Subject_Id
      ,sm.Subject_Marks
from Student_Marks sm
    inner join Student_details sd
       on sm.Student_Id = sd.ID
where sm.Subject_Id in (select ID
                        from Subject_Name
                        where Sub_Name in ('Maths', 'Physics')
                       )
  and Student_Id in (select ID
                     from Student_details
                     where class in (2,3)
                    );
```

Now, this query is taking too much time to get the results.

How can I optimize this query?

---

Edit:

I am using hibernate for getting the result so the actual query is:

```
select sd.First_Name
      ,sd.Last_Name
      ,sm.Subject_Id
      ,sm.Subject_Marks
from Student_Marks sm
    inner join Student_details sd
        on sm.Student_Id = sd.ID
where sm.Subject_Id in :SubName
  and Student_Id in (select ID
                     from Student_details
                     where class in :ClassIds
                    );
```

Comment: Did you do an `EXPLAIN` to see what is critical there?

Comment: Actually, there are 50K students in student Details and 1cr.+ rows for student Marks. So the query is taking 3+ min. .I want to reduce this time. @B001ᛦ

Comment: What indexes do you have on these tables?  And can you use subject `ID` values instead of the `Sub_Name`?

Comment: subject names and class in the query come as a list from java code. Is there any way to remove this IN from query.@iamdave

Comment: Are you only passing the subject names and not the ID values?  If not, can you change your application to do so?

Comment: Using hibernate for getting the result so the actual query is:

`select sd.First_Name
      ,sd.Last_Name
      ,sm.Subject_Id
      ,sm.Subject_Marks
from Student_Marks sm
    inner join Student_details sd
       on sm.Student_Id = sd.ID
where sm.Subject_Id in :SubName
  and Student_Id in (select ID
                     from Student_details
                     where class in :ClassIds);`

and subName and classIds are list

Comment: More information about your dbms is needed for us to help you. Please [read this note about asking good SQL questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/), and pay attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question. You can also try running your query in [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) with the Show Actual Execution Plan option. The resulting execution plan may recommend an index.

Comment: @iamdave I'm trying to create an indexed view as :

`CREATE VIEW TempPivot
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
select Student_Id, [1], [2], [3],[4],[5]
from ( select Student_Id,Subject_Id,Subject_Marks from Student_Marks) up
PIVOT
(max(Subject_Marks) for Subject_Id in (Maths,Physics,Chemistry,Biology,Computer Science)) as pvt
go


`

Comment: But getting error `Cannot create index on view "TempPivot" because it uses the PIVOT operator. Consider not indexing this view.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select sd.First_Name
      ,sd.Last_Name
      ,sm.Subject_Id
      ,sm.Subject_Marks
from Student_Marks sm
     inner join Student_details sd on sm.Student_Id = sd.ID
     inner join Subject_Name sn on sm.Subject_Id = sn.ID AND Sub_Name in ('Maths','Physics')
     inner join Student_details on Student_Id = Student_details.ID AND class in (2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the student detail subquery. Why say "give me student details that you find when looking up student detail the class of which is 2 or 3" instead of "give me student details the class of which is 2 or 3"?

```
select
  sd.sd.first_name,
  sd.last_name,
  sm.subject_id,
  sn.sub_name,
  sm.subject_marks
from student_marks sm
join student_details sd on sd.id = sm.student_id and sd.class in (2, 3)
join subject_name sn on sn.id = sm.subject_id and sn.sub_name in ('Maths', 'Physics');
```

As to `subject_name`: I join the table, so I can show its name. It would make little sense to select the IDs only and have to guess which is Maths and which is Physics.

You should provide the following indexes:

```
create index idx1 on subject_name(sub_name, id);
create index idx2 on student_details(class, id);
create index idx3 on student_marks(student_id, subject_id);
create index idx4 on student_marks(subject_id, student_id);
```

or even covering indexs:

```
create index idx1 on subject_name(sub_name, id, sub_name);
create index idx2 on student_details(class, id, first_name, last_name);
create index idx3 on student_marks(student_id, subject_id, subject_marks);
create index idx4 on student_marks(subject_id, student_id, subject_marks);
```

Whether index idx3 or idx4 will be used, I cannot say. Try them and drop the unused one. (Of course it can happen that the DBMS decides not to use the indexes at all; they are just an offer.)